# conversion from LocalDate to Date for class instantiation is not working

Tags: javafx, datepicker, tableview, tablecolumn, localdate

this new project I am working on, we are supposed to build a GUI Application to act as a sheriff booking system for inmates. I feel like I'm on the right track but I'm starting to hit a few snags.

I'm having a little trouble with datePickers and passing the date into an "Inmate"(class) instantiation. no compile errors but a few are happening as I try to add the inmate from the user input. It will not let me choose the arrestDate first without throwing a nullpointerexception, but if I start from release date then I don't get the same problem and i do not know why. I'm using a tableView to display all the values since its the easiest way to get around sorting that I've found.  I think the errors are coming from trying to convert LocalDate into a Date and then passing it to the instantiation. I'm trying to avoid using a database since I have no training on how to do so with java yet though.

There is also a weird error with one of my columns not showing the data it should be and I cannot seem to find what I'm doing wrong. its with the inmateIDCol. it won't show any of the ID's i have preset.

I also don't understand why can't edit the cells themselves.

I still plan to implement a filter to the tableview, and a visitors log. But i can't seem to wrap my head around how to change the tableview with a visitors log tableview without adding a new window. just making one dissappear and the next pop up would be perfect too.  I would like to add a button that says view visitors log and then a "add" and a "done" button to the visitors log. The done button will return the  original inmate log.

These are my main problems I can't get around at the moment. if you have any tips, ideas, easy fixes, anything I can look at that may help it would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Final extends Application {
String s;
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date arrestDate;
Date courtDate;
Date releaseDate;
int IDNum;


    //build inmates
    ObservableList<Inmate> inmateList;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    //build inmates
    buildInmates();
    //create pane

    TableView tableView = new TableView();//ObservableList<Inmate> inmateList);
    //tableView.setItems(inmateList);
    tableView.setEditable(true);
    //Title
    Label label = new Label("Sheriff Booking System");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 40));
    //set columns
    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Inmate,String>("fName")
    );
    firstNameCol.setEditable(true);
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(150);

    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Inmate,String>("lName")
    );
    lastNameCol.setEditable(true);
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(175);

    TableColumn inmateIDCol = new TableColumn("Inmate ID");
    inmateIDCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Inmate,String>("IDNumber")
    );
    inmateIDCol.setEditable(true);
    inmateIDCol.setMinWidth(100);

    TableColumn cellBlockCol = new TableColumn("Cell Block");
    cellBlockCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Inmate,String>("cellBlock")
    );
    cellBlockCol.setEditable(true);
    cellBlockCol.setMinWidth(100);

    TableColumn heightCol = new TableColumn("Height");
    heightCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Inmate,String>("height")
    );
    heightCol.setEditable(true);
    heightCol.setMinWidth(100);

    TableColumn weightCol = new TableColumn("Weight");
    weightCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Inmate,String>("weight")
    );
    weightCol.setEditable(true);
    weightCol.setMinWidth(100);

    TableColumn ethnicityCol = new TableColumn("Ethnicity");
    ethnicityCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Inmate,String>("ethnicity")
    );
    ethnicityCol.setEditable(true);
    ethnicityCol.setMinWidth(100);

    TableColumn arrestDateCol = new TableColumn("Arrest Date(s)");
    arrestDateCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Inmate,String>("arrestDate")
    );
    arrestDateCol.setMinWidth(150);

    TableColumn courtDateCol = new TableColumn("Court Date(s)");
    courtDateCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Inmate,String>("courtDate")
    );
    courtDateCol.setMinWidth(150);

    TableColumn releaseDateCol = new TableColumn("Release Date(s)");
    releaseDateCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Inmate,String>("releaseDate")
    );        
    releaseDateCol.setMinWidth(150);
    //add values to tableview
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(inmateIDCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol, cellBlockCol, heightCol, weightCol, ethnicityCol, arrestDateCol, courtDateCol, releaseDateCol);

    //textfields to add a new inmate
    HBox hb1 = new HBox();
    hb1.setPadding(new Insets (10));
    hb1.setSpacing(20);
    HBox hb2 = new HBox();
    hb2.setSpacing(20);
    hb2.setPadding(new Insets (10));
    TextField addFName = new TextField();
    addFName.setPromptText("First Name");
    addFName.setMaxWidth(200);

    TextField addLName = new TextField();
    addLName.setPromptText("Last Name");
    addLName.setMaxWidth(200);

    TextField addID = new TextField();
    addID.setPromptText("ID Number");
    addID.setMaxWidth(150);

    TextField addCellBlock = new TextField();
    addCellBlock.setPromptText("Cell Block");
    addCellBlock.setMaxWidth(150);

    TextField addHeight = new TextField();
    addHeight.setPromptText("Height");
    addHeight.setMaxWidth(175);

    TextField addWeight = new TextField();
    addWeight.setPromptText("Weight");
    addWeight.setMaxWidth(175);

    TextField addEthnicity = new TextField();
    addEthnicity.setPromptText("Ethinicty");
    addEthnicity.setMaxWidth(175);

    //datePickers for all date adding
    DatePicker addArrestDate = new DatePicker();
    addArrestDate.setOnAction(e -> {
        LocalDate date = addArrestDate.getValue();
        arrestDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
        //System.out.println("Selected date: " + arrestDate);
    });

    DatePicker addCourtDate = new DatePicker();
    addArrestDate.setOnAction(e -> {
        LocalDate date = addCourtDate.getValue();
        courtDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
        //System.out.println("Selected date: " + courtDate);
    });

    DatePicker addReleaseDate = new DatePicker();
    addArrestDate.setOnAction(e -> {
        LocalDate date = addReleaseDate.getValue();
        releaseDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
        //System.out.println("Selected date: " + releaseDate);
    });
    //button to add new inmate
    Button addButton = new Button("ADD NEW INMATE");
    addButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        IDNum = getInt(addID.getText());
        inmateList.add(new Inmate(
                addFName.getText(),
                addLName.getText(),
                addID.getText(),
                addCellBlock.getText(),
                addHeight.getText(),
                addWeight.getText(),
                addEthnicity.getText(),
                arrestDate,
                courtDate,
                releaseDate));
        addFName.clear();
        addLName.clear();
        addID.clear();
        addCellBlock.clear();
        addHeight.clear();
        addWeight.clear();
        addEthnicity.clear();
        tableView.refresh();
    });
    //labels for datepickers
    Label arrDate = new Label("Arrest Date:");
    arrDate.setFont(new Font("Arial", 18));
    Label courtDate = new Label("Court Date:");
    courtDate.setFont(new Font("Arial", 18));
    Label relDate = new Label("Release Date:");
    relDate.setFont(new Font("Arial", 18));
    Label addNewInmate = new Label("Add New Inmate:");
    addNewInmate.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    tableView.setItems(inmateList);
    //add new inmate textfields and datepickers to view
    hb1.getChildren().addAll( addID, addFName, addLName, addCellBlock, addHeight, addWeight, addEthnicity);
    hb2.getChildren().addAll(arrDate, addArrestDate, courtDate, addCourtDate, relDate, addReleaseDate, addButton);
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, tableView, addNewInmate, hb1, hb2);
    //create date piceker test


    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(vbox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1400, 700);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public ObservableList<Inmate> buildInmates()
{
    inmateList = observableArrayList();
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Joseph", "Levitt", "0001001", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White",new Date(2014, 14,7), new Date(2014, 30, 6), new Date(2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Steve", "Smith", "0001002", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Jordan", "Jones", "0001003", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Samuel", "Adams", "0001004", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Billy", "Joel", "0001006", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Jose", "Cabron", "0001008", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Clark", "Kent", "0001010", "Isolation", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Peter", "Parker", "0001012", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Darrel", "Belk", "0001013", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Shaun", "Stanberry", "0002001", "Maximum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Kemar", "Adjiboue", "0002002", "Maximum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Paul", "Blart", "0002003", "Maximum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Ted", "Bundy", "0002006", "Maximum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Jeffrey", "Jones", "0002004", "Maximum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Geoffrey", "Pittman", "0002009", "Maximum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Michael", "Kersch", "0001021", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Parker", "Smith", "0001022", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Craig", "Robinson", "0001023", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Nigel", "Thornberry", "0001024", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Miguel", "Hinehosa", "0001031", "Minimum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("Charles", "Darwin", "0002015", "Isolation", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));
    inmateList.add( new Inmate("William", "Wundt", "0002007", "Maximum", "6'1", "205.0", "White", new Date( 2014, 14,7), new Date( 2014, 30, 6), new Date( 2002, 30, 9)));


    return null;
}
```

This is the Inmate Class:

```
public class Inmate {

//variables
SimpleStringProperty fName;
SimpleStringProperty lName;
SimpleStringProperty cellBlock;
SimpleStringProperty IDNumber;
SimpleStringProperty height; //initialized with ("#'#")
SimpleStringProperty weight ;
SimpleStringProperty ethnicity;
Date arrestDate;
Date courtDate;
Date releaseDate;
//String visitors;
String s;
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");


public Inmate()
{
    //Default Constructor
    fName = new SimpleStringProperty("Jon");
    lName = new SimpleStringProperty("Doe");
    cellBlock = new SimpleStringProperty("Minimum Security");
    IDNumber = new SimpleStringProperty("00000001");
    height = null;
    weight = new SimpleStringProperty("0.0");
    ethnicity = new SimpleStringProperty("Unknown");
    arrestDate = new Date();
    courtDate = new Date();
    releaseDate = new Date();

}
//minimal constructor
public Inmate(String fName, String lName, String IDNumber, String cellBlock)
{
    this.fName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
    this.lName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
    this.cellBlock = new SimpleStringProperty(cellBlock);
    this.IDNumber = new SimpleStringProperty(IDNumber);
    height = null;
    weight =  new SimpleStringProperty("0.0");
    ethnicity = new SimpleStringProperty("Unknown");
    arrestDate = new Date();
    courtDate = new Date();
    releaseDate = new Date();
}
//full constructor
public Inmate(String fName, String lName, String IDNumber, String cellBlock, String height, String weight, String ethnicity, Date arrestDate, Date courtDate, Date releaseDate)
{
    this.fName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
    this.lName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
    this.cellBlock = new SimpleStringProperty(cellBlock);
    this.IDNumber = new SimpleStringProperty(IDNumber);
    this.height = new SimpleStringProperty(height);
    this.weight = new SimpleStringProperty(weight);
    this.ethnicity = new SimpleStringProperty(ethnicity);
    this.arrestDate = arrestDate;
    this.courtDate = courtDate;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
}

//set and get first name
public void setFName(String name)
{
    this.fName.set(name);
}
public String getFName()
{
    return fName.get();
}

//get and set last name
public void setLname(String name)
{
    this.lName.set(name);
}
public String getLName()
{
    return lName.get();
}

//set and get cell block
public void setCellBlock(String cell)
{
    this.cellBlock.set(cell);
}
public String getCellBlock()
{
    return cellBlock.get();
}

//set and get ID number
public void setIDNumber(String num)
{
    this.IDNumber.set(num);
}
public String getID()
{
    return IDNumber.get();
}

//set and get height
public void setHeight(String height)
{
    this.height.set( height);
}
public String getHeight()
{
    return height.get();
}

//set and get weight
public void setWeight(String weight)
{
    this.weight.set(weight);
}
public String getWeight()
{
    return weight.get();
}

//set and get ethnicity
public void setEthnicity(String race)
{
    this.ethnicity.set(race);
}
public String getEthnicity()
{
    return ethnicity.get();
}


//set and get arrest date
public void setArrestDate (Date date)
{
    arrestDate = date;
}
public String getArrestDate()
{
    return formatter.format(arrestDate);
}

//set adn get court date
public void setCourtDate (Date date)
{
    courtDate = date;
}
public String getCourtDate()
{
    return formatter.format(courtDate);
}

//set and get release date
public void setReleaseDate(Date date)
{
    releaseDate = date;
}
public String getReleaseDate()
{
    return formatter.format(releaseDate);
}

}
```

Comment: Why don't you try to use LocalDate instead of java.sql.date? It's a newer class that came with Java 8 and has greater possibilities and it's easier to work with. Also, did you try to use java.util.date instead? Again, I don't see why you would use java.util.date when you have java.time (LocalDate)

Comment: Also, I never personally worked with javafx, but what does the TextField.getText() method do. I get it that it returns a String, but does it also remove the text. I'm asking because what's different in your code between addID and the other TextFields is that you call getText() twice. So, maybe you can try to save the value like you already did using field IDnum and use that value when you add new Inmate to the inmateList instead of addID.getText()

Comment: It seems to me you are asking more than one question in your question, and giving us a lot of code. Stack Overflow works better with one clear question at a time and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).